# Why does the empty method appendTo make sense?

Tags: java, methods, implementation

In java 7 am using the **PropertyChangeEvent** class and suddenly I found this:

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of the object.
 *
 * @return a string representation of the object
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getClass().getName());
    sb.append("[propertyName=").append(getPropertyName());
    appendTo(sb);   // <----HERE
    sb.append("; oldValue=").append(getOldValue());
    sb.append("; newValue=").append(getNewValue());
    sb.append("; propagationId=").append(getPropagationId());
    sb.append("; source=").append(getSource());
    return sb.append("]").toString();
}

void appendTo(StringBuilder sb) {
}
```

What is driving me crazy, why calling the method `appendTo()`?

Especially as that  method is doing nothing?

Does this make any sense that I can not find at 1st sight?

Comment: The package explanation from @GhostCat was a KO fact, no child class will be able to override the appendTo method.....

Comment: I guess you could theoretically come in, define your own "java.beans" package and do some dirty stuff in there. But obviously: the longer we talk about this to think up how to "exploit" this "feature" in a meaningful way; the clearer it becomes, that it ain't a feature ...

Comment: @GhostCat I think if you try to do that you will get an exception... ***java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.beans***

Comment: I am sure one could work around that; it just doesn't make any sense ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that implementation:

```
void appendTo(StringBuilder sb) {
}
```

I think: this is a "leftover"; an artifact of something that was intended to be done; but simply forgotten.

That method is package protected; so you can only override it within subclasses in the same package; but nowhere else. And: it is not documented anywhere. Thus **no** user of the PropertyChangEvent class would even notice that this method *could* be overridden.

There is no **meaningful** reason to do something like this. Thus my (opinionated) answer: this is a bug; or more precisely; it is a **fault** in the source code; but one that luckily will not cause a **failure** at runtime. Well, unless some poor individual happens to extends this class; and happens to write up such an appendTo() method that does something really weird.

Of course, it is *possible* to do something like this; for example to give extending classes an ability to **insert** some custom element into the result of `toString()`. But if that was the goal of this construct; it fails miserably; as that is not documented.

Comment: Bugs in the extremely well written Java library code? Surely not? Sadly you're probably correct. Have an upvote.

Comment: Lets put it that way: it is half of a bug. It is definitely something that should **not** exist in that class in the way it is written right now.

Answer (score 5):

It makes perfect sense if a child class *overrides* the `appendTo` method.

That's how specific child class stuff can be injected into this function. (Although a comment to that effect would have been nice).

The alternative approach - necessitating a complete override of `toString` - could lead to a fair bit of code duplication.

Comment: should not then be the class abstract instead?

Comment: That might have been a pain in the backside if you were compelled to derive from `String`.

Comment: In general: yes. But here - that method is package protected; it is not documented **anyway**. This is not a feature, it is a bug that doesn't cause harm.